# the add method of LinkedList (with supertype) isn't every thing alright?

Tags: java, generics

```
package pkg_2;

import java.util.*;

class shape{}

class Rect extends shape{}

class circle extends shape{}

class ShadeRect extends Rect{}

public class OnTheRun {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        ShadeRect sr = new ShadeRect();
        List<? extends shape> list = new LinkedList<ShadeRect>();       
        list.add(0,sr);
    }

}
```

Comment: So, what are you asking here?

Comment: Lowercase class names are not exactly right.

Comment: compiler is complaining about the last line & tell me error i cannot understanding it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot add anything to a `List<? extends X>.`

The `add` cannot be allowed because you do not know the component type.  Consider the following case:

```
List<? extends Number> a = new LinkedList<Integer>();
a.add(1);  // in this case it would be okay
a = new LinkedList<Double>();
a.add(1);  // in this case it would not be okay
```

For `List<? extends X>` you can only get out objects, but not add them.
Conversely, for a `List<? super X>` you can only add objects, but not get them out (you can get them, but only as Object, not as X).

This restriction fixes the following problems with arrays (where you are allowed these "unsafe" assigns):

```
Number[] a = new Integer[1];
a[0] = 1;  // okay
a = new Double[1];
a[0] = 1;  // runtime error
```

As for your program, you probably just want to say `List<shape>`. You can put all subclasses of shape into that list.

```
ShadeRect sr = new ShadeRect();
List<shape> list = new LinkedList<shape>();       
list.add(0,sr);
```